# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am writing a piece of code that returns the top 10 documents according to their relevance. But I am getting an error. My code where I believe the error occurs is the sorted_disc_max_10:

```
#sort the term frequency values in ascending order
    sorted_dic = sorted(tf.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    sorted_disc_max_10 = heapq.nlargest(10, sorted_dic,key=lambda s: range(1))

   #print the top 10 document IDs with the most f-idf weighting of a term
    for value in sorted_disc_max_10:
    print (value[0])
```

**The error message that I get is:**

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'

Any ideas about how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: You probably didn't mean to use `range(1)` as a sorting key. Did you mean `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`, as in the previous sort?

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly where the error occurs. In fact it occurs in the `lambda s: range(1)`. Usually the `key` parameter provides a function that takes an item and returns a value to sort it by. For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age')

people = [
    Person('Bob', 35),
    Person('Sarah', 31),
    Person('Jane', 42),
]

people_sorted_by_age = sorted(people, key=lambda p: p.age)
```

In your case, `key=lambda s: range(1)` returns `range(1)` as the value to compare for each item in `sorted_dic`. This doesn't really make sense, because using a constant value as a key won't shuffle any of the items (so no sorting occurs) but as the error indicates you can't compare `range` objects:

```
>>> range(10) < range(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'
```

Under the hood, `nlargest` is using `<` to compare the key values. But comparing ranges really doesn't make sense anyway. You probably want to compare by something else.

But in your previous line you already have the the items in `tf` sorted by `item[1]` (`for item in tf`), so you probably don't need the `nlargest` at all. It's already sorted.

But if you do only need the largest 10, then use `nlargest` instead of sorted for a more efficient sort (since it doesn't sort the entire list):

```
sorted_dic = heapq.nlargest(10, tf.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

If there aren't many items in `tf`, `sorted` is usually the more idiomatic approach. If you want to go that route you can slice off the top 10 items from it:

```
sorted_dic = sorted(tf.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have almost got it working now by using the nlargest(). The only problem I am having now is that the error is now: TypeError: nlargest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reverse'

Comment: Ah whoops, `nlargest` has no `reverse` like sort. If you want the smallest 10 you use `nsmallest`. If you want the top 10, use just `nlargest` without the `reverse` kwarg.

Comment: There's no reason to use `sorted` even if `tf` is small. `sorted` still needs linear memory, because it returns a fully realized list; `largest` only needs to allocate space for 10 items, because as soon as an element becomes the 11th largest, you no longer need to keep it around.